# How can I update my PHP 5.3.3 to PHP 5.3.8 Linux Centos

Tags: php, linux, centos6

I want to update my **php 5.3.3** to **php 5.3.8**, I already downloaded **PHP5.3.8.tar.gzip**.

My **PHP 5.3.3**  located in **/usr/bin/php**. When I try to install **PHP5.3.8.tar.gzip** and do this command:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

It installed in different location **/usr/local/bin/php**.

So now I have 2 **php 5.3.3** and **php 5.3.8**. So I try to install it again and run this

```
./configure -prefix=/usr/bin/php
make
make install
```

This time an error occurred:

```
Installing PHP SAPI module:       cgi
mkdir: cannot create directory `/usr/bin/php': File exists
mkdir: cannot create directory `/usr/bin/php/bin': Not a directory
make: [install-sapi] Error 1 (ignored)
Installing PHP CGI binary: /usr/bin/php/bin/
cp: accessing `/usr/bin/php/bin/#INST@29239#': Not a directory
make: *** [install-sapi] Error 1
```

Please help me, I want to delete the php5.3.8 I installed in /usr/local/bin/php
and update the /usr/bin/php to php5.3.8. I need php5.3.8 version only.

Thanks.

Comment: use this link http://atik97.wordpress.com/2010/06/12/how-to-upgrade-to-php-5-3-in-ubuntu-9-10/

Comment: @jetawe I'm using Centos 6. And I want my php 5.3.3 upgrade to 5.3.8.

Comment: You're overwriting the PHP that centos installed. Generally not a good idea.

Comment: @Marc B So what should I do? Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

Generally on CentOS, you want to leave this sort of thing to yum.

```
yum update php
```

or

```
sudo yum update php
```

You can also replace the installation with a newer version. 5.3.X is not supported any longer, so you could do:

```
yum install yum-plugin-replace
yum replace php --replace-with php55
```

If you don't have php 5.5 in yum, first do this:

```
cd ~
wget http://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/stable/CentOS/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-5.noarch.rpm
wget http://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/stable/CentOS/6/x86_64/ius-release-1.0-11.ius.centos6.noarch.rpm
rpm -Uvh epel-release-6-5.noarch.rpm ius-release-1.0-11.ius.centos6.noarch.rpm
```

If you don't have wget installed:

```
yum install wget
```

**PLEASE NOTE FOR ALL OTHERS FINDING THIS THROUGH GOOGLE!!!**

The URL's that I linked in the wget commands are the current releases of the epel and ius repos for **CentOS 6**. (It may also be out of date.)

If you have RHEL or CentOS 5, you can find the specific link for your RPM here: http://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/stable/

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need 5.3.8 specifically? The last version of 5.3 was 5.3.27. 5.3 is [end-of-life](http://php.net/archive/2013.php#id2013-07-11-1). I would find a modern repo like [remi](http://blog.famillecollet.com/pages/Config-en) and install 5.4 or later using yum